# Nuxt 3 multiple params in dynamic route

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

Is it possible to have dynamic route with multiple params in Nuxt 3.

example:

```
pages/
|---detail/
|-----[category]/
|--------[productSlug]-[id].vue
```

And if i have URL that goes something like this: /detail/test/test-product-12
and when display parameters, it displays like:

```
category: test,
productSlug: test,
id: product-12
```

So my question is, is it possible to have URL like /detail/test/test-product-12 and to display paramas like:

```
category: test,
productSlug: test-product,
id: 12
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use all of these parameters via the route object:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const route = useRoute()

console.log(route.params.category)
console.log(route.params.productSlug)
console.log(route.params.id)
</script>
```

You got one issue here though:

You are splitting the values with `-`: `[productSlug]-[id].vue`while at the same time, your productSlug contains `-`. It will resolve it from front to back as far as I know, so this might work right away how you expect.

Your example: /detail/test/**test-product-12**

However I would suggest to do either of two things:

- Change your split-character to something else
- Don't use `-` in your productSlug, so it is not confusing.

Comment: Does it work for you @almir-pehlivanović? Please accept the answer if it does, otherwise I might be able to help further.