# How do I make a dynamic route in nuxt

Tags: html, dynamic, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I need help because I have a api route that works like this localhost:3000/api/info/${id}
and I want to set it up so I can go to localhost:3000/info/${id}
and it will have the data that gets returned depending on what id is provided but idk how

I haven't tried anything because I don't know how to use the dynamic routes

Answer (score 0):

You need to access route parameters and implement value into API call. https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-route

useRoute method enables you to access route parameters.

```
const route = useRoute()
```

In your case something like this might work.

```
const route = useRoute()
const { data: info} =await useFetch(`/api/info/${route.params.id}`)
```

Question has been previously answered.

[Dynamic routing in Nuxt3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77083550/dynamic-routing-in-nuxt3)

[Nuxt 3 multiple params in dynamic route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76662750/nuxt-3-multiple-params-in-dynamic-route)

Comment: add me on discord @hirobebroke if possible I have other questions that I can't solve wit this same type of thing